# How to set dynamic locations in an Image using actionscript3.0?

Tags: actionscript-3

I want to set different locations in an Image, and when I mouse over the location it needs to shows something('box' or 'x' nd 'y' position of the location). How can i achieve this.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope, you want to set some locations in the stage and u want to store something.

If that, your coding is good. here after u can achieve that by using amf-php for back end purpose. php will help u store values in the database. refer google to know about amf-php.

good luck.

Answer (score 0):

not sure wht you are looking for, may be something like that 
http://www.oscartrelles.com/archives/dynamic_movieclip_registration_with_as3

Answer (score 0):

Not registration point...

```
var msgBox:messageBox;//package

var loc:Array = new Array();
for(var i:uint = 0;i<20;i++)
{
    for(var j:uint = 0;j<14;j++)
    {
        spr = new Sprite();
        spr.graphics.beginFill(0xaaaaaa,.1);
        spr.graphics.drawCircle(0,0,10);
        spr.graphics.endFill();
        addChild(spr);
        loc.push(spr);
        spr.x = 30 + i * spr.width * 1.3;
        spr.y = 30 + j * spr.height * 1.3;  
    }

}
for(i=0; i<loc.length;i++)
{
    loc[i].name = "unknown "+i;
    loc[i].buttonMode = true;
    loc[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, mouseOverAction);
    loc[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, mouseOutAction);
}
function mouseOverAction (e:MouseEvent):void 
{
    msgBox = new messageBox(100,20,6,0xFFFFFF);
    addChild(msgBox);
    cur_loc_name = new TextField();
    cur_loc_name.text = e.target.name;
    msgBox.addChild(cur_loc_name);
    cur_loc_name.x = 5;
    cur_loc_name.y = 1;
    msgBox.x = mouseX + 20;
    msgBox.y = mouseY + 26;
}
function mouseOutAction (e:MouseEvent):void 
{
    removeChild(msgBox);
}
```

Run this code. It will fill the stage with 280 sprites, and each sprite can have diff instance name..

I wants to do this using pixels...or any other way to do?

Comment: Hi Benny, welcome to Stack Overflow! I suggested an edit to your answer to put your code into a code block. Feel free to edit it again if you want to change anything else.

Comment: Oh, and in response to the last part of your answer, I would suggest asking a question of your own (using http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask ) and linking to this question.